# Dynamixel Speed control / wheel (continuous rotation) mode

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have started working with Dynamixel motors (RX-64), and I know that it is possible to use the motor in a continuous rotation (a.k.a wheel) mode. I can't seem to figure out how this should be done?

Somewhere I found that if I set the motor's CW and CCW angles to 0, it should change to a speed controller, but I can't figure out how?
I have tried calling a service of set_speed.

In addition, can someone explain what does the values in the motor field in the tilt.yaml file?
There is init, min, max. I understand that it is something to do with the angles, but don't understand what.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246865/dynamixel-speed-control-/-wheel-(continuous-rotation)-mode/) by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/CreatingJointPositionController   // This link has information about what init, min, max refers to

http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20joint%20torque%20controller // This link as it officially states is the way we can run the dynamixel motors in wheel mode

Idk if it is helpful or not now.

---

Originally posted by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) with karma: 105 on 2017-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2